# Lock on object comparison when a property of object is changed

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Imagine a situation where I'm given this structure (please note, that this can't be changed):

```
struct Point { ... }
class MyClass 
{
   public Point _point;
}
```

This structure is used in a program which is running on multiple threads. The field *_point* is modified during the parallel process (meaning it is read and written) so I need a lock for the given object when accessing this field - this is achieved by doing this (I'm using the object for the lock, I don't want to change this either):

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
lock (myObject)
{
   myObject._point = ...;
}
```

This is all good. Although somewhere (still in the parallel process) I have a comparison like this:

```
MyClass anotherObject = new MyClass();
if (myObject == anotherObject)
{
  DoSomething();
}
```

Note, that the == operator is not overloaded in MyClass. So, my ultimate question is whether I would need to lock those 2 objects (*myObject* and *anotherObject*) to do the comparison or is it fine just to leave it like this? What does the base == operator really do? According to the documentation it *"returns true if its two operands refer to the same object"*. Does that mean that it only compares the addresses of the objects? In that case a lock shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: According to the code you reported and since the `==` operator is not overloaded in MyClass, it seems impossible to me that anotherObject, that is just instantiated, could be equal to another existing instance of MyClass. However if myObject and anotherObject refer to the same instance, than locking on one reference is equivalent to locking on the other reference.

Comment: `The field _point is modified during the parallel process (meaning it is read and written) so I need a lock for the given object when accessing this field ` No, you don't, as long as you're doing atomic operations. Likewise, the comparison is thread-safe if you didn't override the == operator, so you don't need to lock